# Dynamically load/unload modules in Elixir, something like a plugin system

Tags: elixir

I want to create something like a plugin system: a bunch of modules which get loaded/unloaded dynamically, add I insert/remove them.

Something like this:

```
# plugin1.eex
defmodule MyApp.Plugins.Plugin1 do

  def plugin_main_func(arg1, arg2) do
    # some stuff
  end
end

# plugin2.eex
defmodule MyApp.Plugins.Plugin2 do

  def plugin_main_func(arg1, arg2) do
    # some stuff 2
  end
end


# plugin3.eex
defmodule MyApp.Plugins.Plugin3 do

  def plugin_main_func(arg1, arg2) do
    # some stuff 3
  end
end
```

They'll have the same common function - "plugin_main_func" - which implementation will be different for each plugin.
And somewhere in my app I'll have this:

```
plugins = load_plugins()
Enum.each plugins, &(&1.plugin_main_func(1, "fdafdsfds"))
```

I then be able to add or remove plugins by creating or removing appropriate modules or files. **Without** having to hard-code/add/remove their names somewhere in an application as a list of strings **as well**.

How can I achive this?

**Update:**

Given that a plugin must live in MyApp.Plugins and have a function  `plugin_main_func`, how can I observe a list of plugins they are currently present? I mere want to avoid hard-coding their names somewhere and load or run them only having these 2 conditions which are sufficient for finding all the plugins.

When I find all of them, dynamically or semi-dynamically, I want to somehow be able to call `plugin_main_func` in each plugin. Without knowing the number of plugins and their exact names. How?

I'm fine with loading them before compilation, not exactly at runtime.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering the question, stated in the title: yes, it is possible to dynamically load/unload modules in Elixir. Compile code with e.g. [`Code.ensure_compiled/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#ensure_compiled/1) and purge it with Erlang’s [`code`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/code.html#delete-1) module:

```
:code.delete MyApp.Plugins.Plugin1
:code.purge MyApp.Plugins.Plugin1
```

---

Answering the whole question: you are doing it wrong. Elixir is a compiled language and you are abusing it. Compilation in a runtime is definitely not what Elixir is good for.

All you need is to keep a list of “loaded” plugins to fake the behavior you are trying to achieve. `load` would add a module name to a list and `unload` would remove it from there. And that is it. You do not need to load/unload anything in a runtime: it’s extremely ineffective, dangerous and counter-idiomatic. If you need good runtime plugin support—go for [lua](/questions/tagged/lua), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [python](/questions/tagged/python) or even [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

---

To get the list of loaded modules in a runtime, one might use:

```
:application.get_key(:my_app, :modules)
```

You might restrict plugins to the desired namespace (e.g. `MyApp.Plugins`) and filter the list by that name.

Comment: note that I don't know in advance the list of plugins -- no hard-coding. I want Elixir to find that out

Comment: `Answering the whole question: you are doing it wrong. .... All you need is to keep a list of “loaded” plugins to fake the behavior you are trying to achieve. ` -- how to do it right? can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: I have updated the answer with how to get the list of modules in the runtime. For how to do it right, read the second part of my answer _till the end_. Also, I doubt you understand what [tag:elixir] is good for and what it is not and building the plugin system (besides that I can not imagine the use-case for it in OTP) requires way better understanding of the language core, OTP principles and erlang infrastructure that you currently have.

Comment: `load would add a module name to a list and unload would remove it from there. ` -- this is require knowing their exact names or hard-coding them. I don't want it.

Comment: To find them use the code I provided in the third part of my answer. Reading answers helps. To call them use [`Kernel.apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3). To make it explicitly defined, use behaviors (see the link in my comment to @PatNowak’s answer.)

Comment: And, please, for God’s sake stop abusing code formatter (backticks) for emphasis. If you can not tune your keyboard to have proper quotes (“”)—just use markdown’s emphasis formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided by @mudasobwa is really great. All I can do is to give you a hint how to achieve what you want in runtime (by the way - you're trying to use "polymorphism" in the Elixir, nice).

Assuming that these modules are loaded, I wouldn't deal with the compiler to load / remove them. Consider to use any thing that store the state - `:ets`, GenServer, Agent etc.

I would go with implementing my own GenServer, because it gives flexibility with freedom to customize it as much as I want. Imagine the case where `load_plugins()` make a `call` on your GenServer eg.

```
def load_plugins do
  GenServer.call(MyServer, :load_plugins)
end
```

And your GenServer starts with the predefined list of plugins and you defines the API to add / remove them in the state. There's definitely no need to load / compile them in the runtime, even if it's possible.

**Update**

You can always use `Code.ensure_loaded?` to check whether module is loaded:

```
iex(1)> Code.ensure_loaded?(MyApp.Repo)
true

iex(2)> Code.ensure_loaded?(MyAppppppppp.Reeeeppo)
false
```

Comment: Polymorphism in Elixir is usually achieved with [`Protocols`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html) and/or [`Behaviors`](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html#behaviours), not with a runtime code compilation :)

Comment: Yes, but this is also something that reminds the Polymorphism and duck typing ;)

Comment: Duck typing in Elixir is usually achieved with [`Kernel.apply/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#apply/3) I know, I am boring. :)

Comment: Actually you're not :) Thanks for that info.